# How to call method in the weeks given in PHP?

Tags: php, timestamp, numbers

```
$timestampmostfinishedweekly = "2019-09-27 13:46:30";
$timestampmostlocalrecordsweekly = "2019-10-04 13:00:00";
$start_datemostfinishedweekly = date($timestampmostfinishedweekly);
$start_datemostlocalrecordsweekly = date($timestampmostlocalrecordsweekly);
$expiresmostfinishedweekly = strtotime('+7 days', strtotime($timestampmostfinishedweekly));
$expiresmostlocalrecordsweekly = strtotime('+7 days', strtotime($timestampmostlocalrecordsweekly));
$expiresmostfinishedweekly2 = strtotime('+14 days', strtotime($timestampmostfinishedweekly));
```

I will set  $timestampmostfinishedweekly and $timestampmostlocalrecordsweekly to automatically.

Eg: There are 52 weeks in a year.
I will run $timestampmostfinishedweekly on the 10,20,30th week, and $timestampmostlocalrecordsweekly on different weeks automatically.
how can I do this?
I will change this line: "$timestampmostfinishedweekly = "2019-09-27 13:46:30";" tto something like this: $timestampmostfinishedweekly = "monday-week10, monday-week20, monday-week30.
It is possible?

Comment: I have no idea what you want.

Comment: I this line "$timestampmostfinishedweekly = "2019-09-27 13:46:30";" I give the date manually. I will get the date automatically. E.g:$timestampmostfinishedweekly = "monady-week10, monday-week20, monday-week30";

Comment: I still have no idea what you want.

Comment: I updated my question. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found this and its working:

```
$datee=date("W");
if ($datee==10 || $datee==20){
$vacak = date("jS F, Y", strtotime('friday')); 
print_r($vacak);
}
```